# Override web.config in ASP.NET sub-application

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config

IIS 7 .NET 4.0
I have a website with 4 sub-web-applications.
3 of them need settings from the parent-web.config
One should have a completely independent web.config (no inheritance)
I am aware of the possibility to turn off inheritance for sub-apps.
But what I need is a way to turn it off for only one sub-app! (without having to  each section individually..
So I am looking for something like a "dontInheritParentConfig" setting in my sub-web.config

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure it needs to be a 'sub-app'? what if you built it as a sperate website and redirect the 'sub-app-ish' url to it?

Comment: Nevertheless I would like to "nest" my new App inside my Old one without inheriting the web.config for this one only!

Comment: What you want does not exist(yet). You can use a combination of <clear/> and <remove/> for sections in child configs or block at the root with location and Dontinheritinchildapplications and try to script something for this with powershell or appcmd

Answer (score 0):

In .net 4 you can use [Web.config Transformation Syntax for Web Application Project Deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx).  This is a templating change to web.config to allow the file to be different in different scenarios - which should fit with your sub application need.

> Web.config files typically include
>   settings that have to be different
>   depending on which environment the
>   application is running in. For
>   example, you might have to change a
>   database connection string or disable
>   debugging when you deploy a Web.config
>   file. For Web application projects,
>   ASP.NET provides tools that automate
>   the process of changing (transforming)
>   Web.config files when they are
>   deployed. For each environment that
>   you want to deploy to, you create a
>   transform file that specifies only the
>   differences between the original
>   Web.config file and the deployed
>   Web.config file for that environment.